# Multiple Lookbehind regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the text

```
aaabbbbbabbbbab<name>NAME1</name>qweqwe<surname>SURNAME1</surname>
<name>NAME2</name>qweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeqwe<surname>SURNAME1</surname>
```

and the regexpr

```
 (?<=<name>).+?(?=<\/name>)|(?<=<surname>).+?(?=<\/surname>)
```

which gives me 1 matching array (group) as:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => NAME1
            [1] => SURNAME1
            [2] => NAME2
            [3] => SURNAME1
        )

)
```

How do I need to change the regexp in order to get 2 matching arrays (1 for name, 2 for surname)

Comment: Is this XML? If so you will be better off using an XML Parser

Comment: @Alex K No, it is simplified HTML that I have. Parser probably would be better but anyway regexpr is interesting to me

Comment: Why do you need 2 different arrays?

Comment: @anubhava just as a matter of interest. But, yes, it might be better to have a single array and then slice it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$0` is usually the full match. To only get 2 arrays could capture `surname` in the lookahead:

```
(?<=<name>)[^<]+(?=.*?<surname>([^<]+))
```

[Test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yY4cP7/1); Use with `s` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to make the dot also match newlines if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use capturing groups. Names are stored inside group index 1 and surnames are stored inside group index 2.

```
(?<=<name>)(.+?)(?=<\/name>)|(?<=<surname>)(.+?)(?=<\/surname>)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pC4hU6/1)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate approach:**

Consider using:

```
preg_match_all('~<(?<tag>name|surname)>(?<value>.+?)</\1>~is', $input, $matches);
```

This will give following content in `$matches` array:

```
Array (
    ...
    [tag] => Array (
            [0] => name
            [1] => surname
            [2] => name
            [3] => surname
        )
    [value] => Array (
            [0] => NAME1
            [1] => SURNAME1
            [2] => NAME2
            [3] => SURNAME1
        )    
)
```

Now you can match entries using `tag` array and `value` array.